# WiX: Show a UI Dialog-Element after "InstallFinalize"

Tags: wix, wix3.8, wix3.10, wix3.11, wix3.9

I would like to show an installation complete message after the installation is finished. But i believe, that the latest point to show a Dialog during the installation is with `<Show Dialog="ExitDialog" OnExit="success"/>`. The problem with this solution is, that the Installation is not finished at this point. The user has to click the "Finalize" button. This is especially a problem, when a process was canceled by the *RestartManager*. This process will be restarted after the user is pressing the finished button. If he forgets to press this button, his system is in a state i don't want.

Is there an option to schedule a Dialog Window after the Installation, like for example inside of a *InstallExecuteSequence* with: `After="InstallFinalize"`. Is that possible to call a Dialog Window after Installation was really finished?

This is a follow up question from: [WiX: How restart the explorer.exe immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60342822/wix-how-restart-the-explorer-exe-immediately)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option. Because all GUI elements are part of the MSI Installation. And normally the installation should be finished when the EndDialog is shown. In my special case the *util:RestartResource* of Wix was restarting all processes in the moment MSI is closing. Because of that it was after all GUI elements.

The only way it could work is to implement a CustomAction which is rendering a window by them self. But it would not recommend this way.

Comment: Is it possible to show a custom dialog before InstallFinalize? I am trying <Show Dialog = "ConfigurationIIS" Before = "InstallFinalize"> </Show> but throw "unresolved reference to symbol" WixAction: InstalllUISequence / InstallFinalize 'in section' Fragment '.